# Select everything from 1 table and only x rows from another

Tags: sql

Im making a join query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Clothes AS C 
JOIN Style AS S on C.StyleId = S.SylelId
WHERE ClothesId = '19'
```

But i dont want to select everything from Style
I want to select everything from Clothes (20 rows)
And only select 1 row (from 10) from Style
What is the easyest way to do this without having to select every row from Clothes (with 20 things to select) like:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Description, C.Name, C.Size, C.Brand, S.Name FROM Clothes AS C 
JOIN Style AS S on C.StyleId = ST.SylelId
WHERE ClothesId = '19'
```

What would be the fastest way? Or is this the only possibillity

Comment: Need more info.  Are you saying that for any one row in clothes, you may have multiple rows in styles?  If so, how do you know which row you want?  Or, as the answers below assume, did you mean you only want one COLUMN from styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table name to the `*`

```
SELECT C.*, S.Name as StyleName
FROM Clothes AS C 
JOIN Style AS S on C.StyleId = S.SylelId
WHERE ClothesId = '19'
```

If you have equal names in both tables you have to alias at least one of them to distinguish them.

Comment: Thx I was wondering that for a long time but couldnt find it !

Comment: supply alias on `s.name` to remove ambiguity error. since both tables have column name `Name`.